# TEST API WITH JEST ( REACT JS ) using axios and interceptors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, axios, interceptor

I'm making a test with mock in my project. but for some reason, i got this error when i run npm test -- api-service.

i'm using jest.

i dont know why i got this error, when i try to run the test.

someone call help me?

api.service.test.js

```
import ApiService from './Api-service';

jest.mock('axios');

it('return wellheads', async () => {
  const wellheads = {
    0: {
      UniqueWellboreIdentifier: 'BR 3-OGX-50D-RJS',
      UniqueWellIdentifier: 'BR 3-OGX-50D-RJS',
      CountryIdentifier: 'Brazil',
      BasinIdentifier: 'Santos',
      FieldIdentifier: 'TUBARAO AZUL',
      Latitude: -23.56569,
      Longitude: -41.445133,
    },
    1: {
      UniqueWellboreIdentifier: 'BR 1-BRSA-532-SPS',
      UniqueWellIdentifier: 'BR 1-BRSA-532-SPS',
      CountryIdentifier: 'Brazil',
      BasinIdentifier: 'Santos',
      FieldIdentifier: 'No field related',
      Latitude: -25.624473,
      Longitude: -43.905731,
    },
  };
  const resp = { data: wellheads };
  axios.interceptors.get.mockResolvedValue(resp);

  return ApiService.getWellhead().then((data) =>
    expect(data).toEqual(wellheads)
  );
});
```

api-interceptors.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { authContext, getAdalApiToken } from '../config/AdalConfig';
import conf, { getResource } from './../settings';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: getResource('psa').ApiBaseUrl,
});

api.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      authContext.acquireToken(conf.AzureADClientId, (message, token, msg) => {
        if (!!token) {
          config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
          resolve(config);
        } else {
          reject(config);
        }
      });
    });
  },
  function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

api.interceptors.response.use(undefined, (err) => {
  if (
    err.response &&
    err.response.status === 401 &&
    err.response.config &&
    !err.response.config.__isRetryRequest
  ) {
    err.response.config.__isRetryRequest = true;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      authContext.acquireToken(conf.AzureADClientId, (message, token, msg) => {
        getAdalApiToken();
        if (!!token) {
          api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
          resolve(err.config);
        } else {
          reject(err.config);
        }
      });

      // authContext.acquireToken(process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID, (message, token, msg) => {
      //   axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
      //   err.config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;

      //   axios(err.config).then(resolve, reject);
      // });
    });
  }
  throw err;
});

export default api;
```

and when i run, the error is:

Test suite failed to runice.test.
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'interceptors' of undefined

```
   7 | });
   8 | 
>  9 | api.interceptors.request.use(
     |     ^
  10 |   (config) => {
  10 |   (config) => {
  11 |     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  12 |       authContext.acquireToken(conf.AzureADClientId, (message, token, msg) => {
```

Comment: You've mocked axios, but not said what its `interceptors` property should be; what did you *expect*?

Comment: and how would i do that? sorry but i'm still a layman in unit tests @jonrsharpe

Comment: The Jest docs have a bunch of stuff about mocks, maybe start there: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html